# Sort NSDictionary as per date-wise in iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, sorting, nsdictionary

I have a dictionary like:

```
{
    "2014-04-12" =     (
                {
            "can_remove" = 1;
            "date_created" = "12-04-2014 04:23:57";
            "is_connected" = 0;
            name = "J J";
            status = gbn;
            "user_id" = 94;
        }
    );
    "2014-04-14" =     (
                {
            "can_remove" = 0;
            "date_created" = "14-04-2014 02:36:52";
            "is_connected" = 0;
            name = abc;
            "user_id" = 89;
        }
    );
}
```

The keys of this dictionary represent dates. How can I sort this by date?

I tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
NSArray* keys = [dict allKeys];
    NSArray* sortedArray = [keys sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(id a, id b) {
        return [a compare:b options:NSNumericSearch];
}];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use following way to sort the dictionary according to date :

```
NSMutableArray *dictKeys = [[dict allValues] mutableCopy];

[dictKeys sortUsingComparator: (NSComparator)^(NSDictionary *a, NSDictionary *b) 
  {
    NSString *key1 = [a objectForKey: @"field3"];  
    NSString *key2 = [b objectForKey: @"field3"];

    return [key1 compare: key2];
  }
];

NSLog (@"dictKeys - %@",dictKeys);
```

Comment: But where is I got the array of sorted keys?

Comment: NSLog(@"%@",sortedArray); here you can get. Check updated code

Comment: [__NSCFString objectForKeyedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1748b250

Comment: @user2893370: You need to do basic things by yourselves. You cannot ask for ready made solutions. We can just guide you.

Answer (score 1):

try this code:

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [[myDict allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
```

Comment: Isn't that equivalent to what he did anyway?

Comment: Thanks for your reply...
I already try this.. But got the answer 

`<__NSArrayI 0x1d015d30>(
2014-04-12,
2014-04-14
)`

Comment: @user2893370, what is wrong with that result? That is exaclty what I'd expect. You created an arrays with keys and got them sorted by key. Go from there.

Answer (score 0):

check this code..

```
// currentDic has all data.

NSArray * tempArray = currentDic.allKeys;

NSDateFormatter * formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];

NSArray * sortedArray = [tempArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSString * obj1, NSString * obj2) {
    NSDate * firstDate = [formatter dateFromString:obj1];
    NSDate * secondDate = [formatter dateFromString:obj2];

    return [firstDate compare:secondDate];

}];
```

if you need it as dictionary then,

```
  NSMutableDictionary * resultingDic = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
  [sortedArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString * obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {

    resultingDic[obj] = currentDic[obj];
}];
```